# how to specify multiple 'Tag' while creating AWS Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK for python to create AWS spot instances, but not getting on how can I specify multiple key-value name pait which will eventually get reflected under 'Tags' section of the created VM.
According to the below API documentation, keyName is the name if the key pair , and I am not sure whether this is related to Tags or not.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances

Answer (score 2):

You can not define tags through `request_spot_instances`. You need to either use `create_tags` after the spot instance request is created or create a Launch template with tags defined in them and then create a spot instance fleet request to have tags.

References:

- [Tagging spot instance requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#concepts-spot-instances-request-tags)
- [Tagging support at launch time using CLI/SDK/API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-resources)
- [Create Launch template](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_launch_template)
- [Request spot fleet](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_fleet)
- [Create tags boto3 reference](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags)